# solving double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve a double integral:

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}-y}24xy\; dx \;dy$

I first solved in respect to $y$, making the $x$ a constant and plugged in the $y$ values then took the derivative with respect to $x$, making the $y$ values a constant.

24 x2/2(1/2-y)2 - x2/2(1/2-0)2 = ?  this is where I am stuck

Answer (score 1):

Agha gave you the answer. So,$$I=\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}-y}24xy \; dx \;dy=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}24\frac{(\frac{1}{2}-y)^2}{2}y - 0;dy=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}(12 y^3-12 y^2+3 y) \;dy$$ Integrating term by term this polynomial, the antiderivative of the integrand is $$3 y^4-4 y^3+\frac{3 y^2}{2}$$ Now, use the bounds and you will obtain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Everything ok, but you should first integrate in respect to $x$, next respect to $y$ (bacause upper limit in second integral). You have:

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}-y}24xy \; dx \;dy=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}24\frac{(\frac{1}{2}-y)^2}{2}y - 0\;dy$

This integral you can easily calculate (polynomial).

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong, I do not get 1/16